# AssertionFailedException: Null Argument at Runtime in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, nullpointerexception, spring-tool-suite

IDE: Spring Tool Suite

Version: 3.9.6

OS: Windows 10

So I decided to switch from Eclipse Oxygen to Spring Tool Suite because Oxygen has a super annoying bug, and I don't have access to a newer version. Spring Tool Suite is built on top of Eclipse so I figured the transition would go smoothly. I worked out all of the errors from the change and my project looks clean, not even a warning. However, when I try to execute my code, I get an `AssertionFailedException`:

[image]

When I try to Maven Clean I get a `NullPointerException`:

[image]

I should point out that these screenshots are of the log file found in the metadata folder in my workspace. STS says it encounters an internal error but not much details so I pulled these from the log file.

I've looked. Believe me I...have...looked for answers, and nothing makes sense in any answer I find. They're talking about viewers and DNE's. What??? Anyway, this also happens with ANY new project I create or import.

Comment: can you provide a few steps to reproduce the issue, starting from a fresh vanilla STS 3.9.6 install?

Comment: So I did not install the application to my local system. The STS package was copied from a remote shared directory. That might be the problem. I was surprised that STS even executed from just copying it from one file system to my local system. I'll try a fresh install and update you.

Comment: @MartinLippert I wasn't able to install from the site due to security restrictions on the machine I'm using. Pretty much, I just copy the full STS directory from a shared network to the machine I'm using, open the IDE, create a new workspace, create a new simple Maven project in the workspace, add a class with the main method and a `System.out.println("Hello")`, then run it. That's when I get the exception. I have a 32-bit JDK so I know that isn't the issue. My environment variables are setup properly. No errors appear in the project.

Comment: what happens if you do an "Maven -> Update Project..." from the context menu in STS?

Comment: It updates fine.

Comment: Hmm, really hard to say what is going wrong here. Could you attach a sample project, so that we could try that locally? And what happens if you use the "Import Getting Started Content" wizard to import one of the Spring guides (for example the "Rest Service" one and run that? Does that work? And can you double check the JRE settings that you have in your preferences? Maybe something is wrong with that.

Comment: It isn't project specific actually. I've triple checked the JRE settings as well. A colleague of mine was having the same issue and she said she figured it out. Unfortunately, she is on vacation at the moment so I will have to wait for her return to get her resolution. I really appreciate your help though Martin. I'll update this post with the answer if her resolution works for me.

Comment: Yes, please update us here about the solution that she found. Would really like to hear about the underlying problem and the solution for this.